# -webkit-filter: brightness() value different for safari? How to work around?

Tags: jquery, css, webkit

I've noticed that safari likes the brightness setting for the -webkit-filter to be a percentage, whereas the other browsers adopt a less obvious scale.

Notice the difference between the brightness changes on this example, in chrome and safari for instance:

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html

Does anyone know of an elegant workaround?

(this is the site I'm implementing it on: http://www.ianbutterworth.co.uk/sun )

Comment: remember that as long as a style is prefixed, it is technically still experimental, and thus there is no guarantee that it will work the same cross browsers. Also, if you're going to use a prefixed `-webkit-` style, don't forget to also include the unprefixed version, as well as any other vendor prefixes that may be supported like `-moz-`.

Comment: I hadn't realised the meaning of the prefix! Thanks.
I actually account for the various prefixes already, but only did because I grabbed them off an example.. now I understand them!

Comment: i.e. 
`$("#sun").click(function(){
 $("#pano").css("-webkit-filter","brightness(1.5) contrast(0.9) saturate(2.3) sepia(0.1)");
   $("#pano").css("-moz-filter","brightness(1.5) contrast(0.9) saturate(2.3) sepia(0.1)");
   $("#pano").css("-ms-filter","brightness(1.5) contrast(0.9) saturate(2.3) sepia(0.1)");
   $("#pano").css("-o-filter","brightness(1.5) contrast(0.9) saturate(2.3) sepia(0.1)");
   $("#pano").css("-filter","brightness(1.5) contrast(0.9) saturate(2.3) sepia(0.1)");
});`

Comment: even better, when it comes to using jQuery (recent versions at least), you don't need to specify the prefixes at all because in many cases jQuery can do automatic prefixing when required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that has been fixed. It's just a matter of waiting for Safari to catch up with Chrome, which will probably have happened by the time you read this.